# youtube downloader by pyscript

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytube, pyscript

I'm trying to make a youtube downloader by `pyscript` but I got this error

```
<py-env>
    - pytube
</py-env>

<py-script >
    from pytube import YouTube
    url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BXJIjfJCsA&t=111s"
    my_video=YouTube(url)
    print(my_video.title)
</py-script>
```

```
JsException(PythonError: Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 429, 
in eval_code .run(globals, locals) 
File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 300, 
in run coroutine = eval(self.code, globals, locals) 
File "", line 4, 
in 
File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytube/__main__.py", line 341, 
in title self._title = self.vid_info['videoDetails']['title'] 
File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytube/__main__.py", line 246, 
in vid_info innertube_response = innertube.player(self.video_id) 
File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytube/innertube.py", line 300, 
in player return self._call_api(endpoint, query, self.base_data) 
File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytube/innertube.py", line 242, 
in _call_api response = request._execute_request( 
File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytube/request.py", line 37, 
in _execute_request return urlopen(request, timeout=timeout) # nosec 
File "/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 216, 
in urlopen return opener.open(url, data, timeout) 
File "/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 519, 
in open response = self._open(req, data) 
File "/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 541, 
in _open return self._call_chain(self.handle_open, 'unknown', 
File "/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 496, 
in _call_chain result = func(*args) 
File "/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1419, 
in unknown_open raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type) urllib.error.URLError:
```

Comment: `PyScript` is not normal Python and some modules may not be ready to work with `PyScript`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web browsers do not allow applications to open TCP sockets. Your application depends on `urllib` which requires TCP sockets. The package `urllib` is not supported by any web browser due to the browser's security sandbox.

Your application and its dependencies must be modified to use supported browser APIs such as `fetch`.